# Showing Macd for MQL5 Expert Advisor

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I have a few experiences to develop on MT4/MQL4.

Now I try to move to MQL5, but I bumped into the problem at first step.

I just want to show the latest MacD and signal for every timeframe.

However It doesn't show the values.

Where is wrong??

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                         test.mq5 |
//|                        Copyright 2020, MetaQuotes Software Corp. |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2020, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

int hMacd;
double bufMacdMain[];
double bufMacdSignal[];

int OnInit()
  {
//---

    SetIndexBuffer(0, bufMacdMain, INDICATOR_DATA);
    //ArraySetAsSeries(bufMacdMain, true);
    SetIndexBuffer(1, bufMacdSignal, INDICATOR_DATA);
    //ArraySetAsSeries(bufMacdSignal, true);    
    hMacd = iMACD(NULL,0,13,26,9,PRICE_CLOSE); 

//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {
//---
     IndicatorRelease(hMacd);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
    if(isNewBar(_Symbol,0)) {
      Print("newbar1");
      CopyBuffer(hMacd, 0, 0, 100, bufMacdMain);
      CopyBuffer(hMacd, 1, 0, 100, bufMacdSignal);
      printf(__FUNCTION__+": MACD = ", bufMacdMain[0], " / ", bufMacdSignal[0]);
    }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool isNewBar(string symbol, ENUM_TIMEFRAMES tf)
{
   static datetime time = 0;
   if(iTime(symbol, tf, 0) != time)
   {
      time = iTime(symbol, tf, 0);
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

---

code updated thanks to @Daniel Kniaz

It works.

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                         test.mq5 |
//|                        Copyright 2020, MetaQuotes Software Corp. |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2020, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

int hMacd;
double bufMacdMain[];
double bufMacdSignal[];

int OnInit()
  {
//---

    SetIndexBuffer(0, bufMacdMain, INDICATOR_DATA);
    ArraySetAsSeries(bufMacdMain, true);
    SetIndexBuffer(1, bufMacdSignal, INDICATOR_DATA);
    ArraySetAsSeries(bufMacdSignal, true);    
    hMacd = iMACD(NULL,0,13,26,9,PRICE_CLOSE); 

//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {
//---
     IndicatorRelease(hMacd);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
    if(isNewBar(_Symbol)) {
      Print("newbar1");
      int macCopied = CopyBuffer(hMacd, 0, 0, 1, bufMacdMain);
      int sigCopied = CopyBuffer(hMacd, 1, 0, 1, bufMacdSignal);
      print("macCopied Num:",macCopied);
      print("sigCopied Num:",sigCopied);
      Print(__FUNCTION__+": MACD = ", bufMacdMain[0], " / ", bufMacdSignal[0]);
    }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool isNewBar(string symbol, ENUM_TIMEFRAMES tf = PERIOD_CURRENT)
{
   static datetime time = 0;
   if(iTime(symbol, tf, 0) != time)
   {
      time = iTime(symbol, tf, 0);
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the handle first, before buffers, and make sure initialization is successful.

What's the need to copy 100 last values of the buffer? Make sure you managed to get them all as CopyBuffer returns number of copied elements (usually all or -1 if any error happened). Also do not forget that you havent ordered the buffers so `bufMacdMain[0]` is likely to be the main buffer of the indicator 99 bars old (in MQL4, 0 means current, in MQL5 - quite opposite unless you clearly told to set array as series)

With your `isNewBar()` funcion I would suggest to pass timeframes as ENUM_TIMEFRAME values because they are quite different (and usually have no sense for those who know MQL4), sth like `isNewBar(string symbol, ENUM_TIMEFRAMES tf=PERIOD_CURRENT){}` and call it without the unnecessary parameter or with a correct timeframe.

MQL5 is fast, but it is not easy to understand

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!! I use `ArraySetAsSeries` and fetch only 1 double value for each time, now it works.

Comment: yes, that's the right approach. If you use comparison in your logic (e.g., macd_main[0]>macd_main[1], then copy 2 elements, 0 would be the latest. Definetely no need in collecting 100 values!